# Is it possible to hook into the image upload function on the wysiwyg editor?

Tags: event-observer, overrides, wysiwyg, upload, image-upload

I'm trying to trigger a function after an image has been uploaded using the wysiwyg editor but I don't think an events is fired after this operation. I know it's relatively easy to do so when you upload product images to the catalog but not so much when adding images to cms pages or static blocks.

I think the `uploadFile` function in the `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage` class is responsible for this so I guess I could override it in my module but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [these instructions](http://inchoo.net/magento/choosing-a-right-event-to-observe/) I was able to log all the events that fire when you upload an image in the cms pages but sadly there is none that let's you hook into specifically to handle the uploaded image.

The closes one I found was `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_cms_wysiwyg_images_thumbnail` and `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_cms_wysiwyg_images_thumbnail` but these run when the thumbnails in the image upload modal are rendered.

I guess overriding the `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage` class is the way to go here.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that in Magento 2 the event `catalog_product_gallery_upload_image_after` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are custom events tied to model classes, check if one of those can be used in your case. They are caled `something_load_after`, `something_load_before`, `something_save_after` and `something_save_before`. Like `model_save_before` but for specific classes. [This](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) is a complete set of events you should check.

Comment: I did go through that very same list but couldn't find anything related to the upload functionality.

Comment: As I told you, there is no event attached to the upload functionality but you can use a model class related to that particular model. Also check the code to see if there is any event dispatched at any point when uploading the image.

Comment: Sadly I haven't been able to find any event, I'll leave this question open in case someone has an idea.